# url passing parameters are not displayed

Tags: cakephp

In cake php **layout/default.ctp**
I created a menu bar but here I done link the URL with like this

```
<li class='active'> <?php //echo $this->Html->link('Psychiatrist', array('controller' => 'pages','action' => 'home','?' => array('id' => '1')));
echo $this->Html->link('Psychiatrist', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'home',5)); ?></li>
   <!-- <li class='active'><a href='#'><span>Podiatrist</span></a></li>-->
    <li class='active'> <?php echo $this->Html->link('Podiatrist', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'home',5)); ?></li></li>
```

It works fine, when we clicked on link url shows as 
**http:/Projects/DoctorSample/pages/home/5**

```
controller /PagesController.php
class PagesController extends AppController {
public function home($id='null'){
        if(isset($id)){
             echo $id;
            }
        }
}
```

But in my display it shows 
Error: The view for PagesController::display() was not found. but I done home.ctp in pages

Answer (score 0):

The problem on your `app/Config/routes.php`  file. 
Delete this line from `app/Config/routes.php` -

```
Router::connect(
’/pages/*
’,
array(’controller’ => ’pages’, ’action’ => ’display’)
);
```